# actix-session invalidate session

Tags: rust, actix-web, rust-actix

I'm currently using [actix session](https://github.com/actix/actix-extras/tree/master/actix-session) with redis
for handling user sessions in web app. I cant figure out how to handle user password reset (aka. "forgot password").

What I mean by password reset:

1. User request password reset and receives an email with reset token
2. User opens form where he submits new password (with received token) to server
3. Server validates reset token and password and stores new hash to database

What I want to do but I have no idea how:

- In step **3.** I want to invalidate any previous **sessions** that user had.

Should I just manually find data in redis and erase it?